# How to calculate diagonal degree matrix from a huge (scipy.sparse) matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Given a quadratic matrix of dimension 1 million I want to calculate the diagonal degree matrix.

The diagonal degree matrix is defined as a diagonal matrix, which has the count of non zero values per row as entrys.

The matrix, let's call it `A` is in format `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`.

If my machine would have enough power I would just do

```
diagonal_degrees = []
for row in A:
    diagonal_degrees.append(numpy.sum(row!=0))
```

I even tried that, but it results in a

```
ValueError: array is too big.
```

So I tried to make use of the sparse structure of scipy. I thought of this way:

```
diagonal_degrees = []
CSC_format = A.tocsc() # A is in scipys CSR format.
for i in range(CSC_format.shape[0]):
    row = CSC_format.getrow(i)
    diagonal_degrees.append(numpy.sum(row!=0))
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there a more efficient way, I maybe have overlooked?
2. While the [docs of scipy sparse state](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html#usage-information):

> All conversions among the CSR, CSC, and COO formats are efficient, linear-time operations.

Why do I get a

```
SparseEfficiencyWarning: changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
```

while changing from CSR to CSC?

Comment: You're getting the error when you set an item in a `csr_matrix`.  "Changing the sparsity structure" has nothing to do with converting between different sparse matrix formats. It's when you add a "dense" item(s).

Comment: If all you need to do is count the non-zero elements, [`nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nonzero.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nonzero) method looks promising.

Comment: As @avaris already pointed you to, you can just do `diag_deg, _ = np.histogram(x.nonzero()[0], np.arange(x.shape[0]+1))`

Comment: @Joe: Please turn this into an answer, so I can vote and accept.

Comment: It should really be @Avaris's, in my opinion, as he was the one to point out `nonzero`.

Comment: Whoeverof you two kind people wants the points, will get them. :-)

Comment: Well, it doesn't really matter to me but to let this question rest, I'll make it an answer :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need is to count the non-zero elements, there is [`nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nonzero.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nonzero) method that could be useful.

Exact code would be (with the help of [Joe Kington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325565/joe-kington) and [matehat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1045904/matehat)):

```
diag_deg, _ = np.histogram(x.nonzero()[0], np.arange(x.shape[0]+1))

# generating a diagonal matrix with diag_deg
dim = x.shape[0]
diag_mat = np.zeros((dim**2, ))
diag_mat[np.arange(0, dim**2, dim+1)] = diag_deg
diag_mat.reshape((dim, dim))
```

Though for large arrays (`dim ~ 1 million`), as noted by [Aufwind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641514/aufwind), `np.zeros((dim**2, ))` gives the exception: `ValueError: Maximum allowed dimension exceeded`. An alternative workaround is to use sparse matrices:

```
diag_mat = sparse.coo_matrix((dim, dim))
diag_mat.setdiag(diag_deg)
```

Comment: Just to add to the great solution, if one wants to generates the diagonal matrix from `diag_deg`, he could write `diag_mat = np.zeros((x.shape[0]**2, ))` then `diag_mat[np.arange(0, x.shape[0]**2, x.shape[0]+1)] = diag_deg` and finally `diag_mat.reshape((x.shape[0], x.shape[0]))`. Sorry about the sparse code … I didn't want to create a new answer for that ;)

Comment: @matehat: Thanks for the completion of the solution. Let `dim = x.shape[0]` Unfortunately `np.zeros((dim**2,))`results in a `ValueError: Maximum allowed dimension exceeded` when `dim` is too high. In my case `dim` is around *one million*. So one should choose an other way when dealing with high dimension matrices. For example: `diag_mat = sparse.coo_matrix((dim,dim))` and then `diag_mat.setdiag(diag_deg)`.

Comment: @Avaris: Perhaps you want to merge those two comments into your answer. So it gets more complete and better to read for people facing a similar problem.

Comment: @Aufwind: Will do. Thanks for notifying.